# Capture stacktrace for all threads when an exception is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, exception

I'm working with a ASP.NET site backed by a WCF service, where the service is throwing exceptions randomly, caught on the site eventually, and creating a YSOD there. I suspect this is due to a threading issue on the backend, and would like to track the issue down.

Is there an easy way to catch the uncaught exception on the WCF side, and also capture the stacktrace of all threads running as well, and rethrow the initial exception with the additional information?

This multiple thread trace seems like something that would come with the framework, or that someone else might have thought about before, but I cant seem find anything.

Comment: You should still be able to hook into the AppDomain.UncaughtException event.

Comment: "eventually" sounds an awful lot like there is an exception in a finalizer... what is the exception? The "eventually" also makes me think that the stack-trace of other threads is not going to be helpful, as they no longer represent the state of the system that led up to the exception. Are you using the `Task` API by any chance?

Comment: @Marc eventually is because the WCF channel times out sometimes. At this point, all hope is lost, but other times, we get a genuine exception, but can't repo it. I hope with the snapshot, it may provide some direction.

Comment: @MarcGravell We are not using the task API on the middle tier. If it is a multi threading issue, I think its due to a concurrent WCF request/thread, around some shared 'resource'.

Comment: I don't see that the stack traces of other threads can matter to you. If the other threads are behaving, then they're doing something that has nothing to do with your request thread. If they're trashing shared data, then they've probably already moved on from where they were at the time they did that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders we have an issue with a part of our system(bad design) with a solution(hack/worse design) in place to stop an error from occuring, only allowing one thread 'in' to the back end at a certain time of day. other requests block until initial request is finished. i wanted to verify they were blocking. eyeballing the stacktrace would allow me to see this (in a log), as it intermittently.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the thread visualization tools in the VS 2010 (and higher) debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to catch the stack traces of the other threads, you'd have to be in the debugger and view their stacks (e.g. with Parallel Stack Window) when the exception is thrown, but that doesn't let you send their traces back.

You could instrument your code (i.e. pepper it in strategic locations) to record stack traces the other thread can get to, but this has nasty performance, maintenance, and elegance issues. Not to mention it would only approximate what the other threads are doing, since they could have advanced independently since the exception was thrown.

The only other way I can think of (and this is conjecture) is somehow aborting the other threads, catching the abort, saving off the stack trace, and then resetting the abort. But this will be likely be a non-deterministic mess. Aborting is not a recommended practice.

You'd probably be best off with a call profiler, generous logging, and narrowing the scope as much as possible to find the root cause.